# differentiating between "past tense" and" present tense"

Tags: tense

1. "I asked my mother, and she said [that] he can go with us."
2. "I asked my mother, and she says [that] he can go with us."
3. "I asked my mother, and she said [that] he could go with us."

Can we say that №№ 1 and 2 can only be said before or during their "going"?
Can we say that № 3 can be said at any moment, that is before, during and after their going?

Could we take number 3 &2 as a fact, fir instance, and 2&3 can be said at any moment?!

Answer (score 1):

Although I generally agree with what you wrote, whether you're quoting your mother [directly or indirectly](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) can influence interpretation.

1a. *I asked my mother and she said, "He can go with us."* [direct quote] 
 can be said at any moment (before, during, or after going)

1b. *I asked my mother and she said that he can go with us.* [indirect quote] 
 before going is implied

2a. **I asked my mother and she says, "He can go with us."* [direct quote] 
 unclear, ambiguous; avoid mixing tenses; 
sounds to me like someone telling a story badly, "Goldilocks opened the door and sees three bowls on the table."

2b. *I asked my mother and she says that he can go with us.* [indirect quote] 
 before going is implied

3a. *I asked my mother and she said, "He could go with us."* [direct quote] 
 can be said at any moment (before, during, or after going)

3b. *I asked my mother and she said that he could go with us.* [indirect quote] 
 can be said at any moment (before, during, or after going)